# MPMoviePlayer how do you detect ONLY when a user seeks forward?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer

Thanks for the assistance, I have a movie player, and I want to prevent a user from scrubbing forward through the movie, but I dont care if they go backwards (rewind). I am detecting when the playback state is changing, and then testing for "MPMoviePlayerDidSeekingForward"

The problem is that playbackState ALWAYS is seeking forward when I scrub the regardless of the direction.

For various reasons I cant make my own custom player, I need to work with the standard MPMoviePlayer.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //movie playback has started go to full screen.

    if(_player.fullscreen == NO){
        _player.fullscreen = YES;
    }

    //prevent user from scrubbing through the movie

//    #ifdef DEBUG
//    
//       return;
//    #else

    if(_player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward){


        NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"you are not allowed to skip the movies"

        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: alertMessage
                                  delegate: self
                         cancelButtonTitle: @"Continue"
                         otherButtonTitles: @"Stop", nil];
        self.isShowing = YES;
        [alert show];

        [_player pause];
        _player.fullscreen = NO;
    }
   // #endif
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to just track what the change in position was between two events?

Comment: I assume you mean checking the current runtime against the new playback location? The problem with that is maintaining a timer that is accurate to the exact playback head location which is why I switched to just try and detect the scrubbing direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put `[_player endSeeking]`
in the

`if(_player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward){` statement?